# How to fetch the name of multiple Buttons present in a single MACRO-VBA file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba, win32com

I've got a MACRO(.xlms) file and want to fetch the name of the multiple buttons given in it. So, from the below code I'm able to fetch the name of a single button MACRO but not able to fetch the name of multiple buttons MACRO. Apology If I've done any mistake in asking the question. i.e I'm new here.

```
input_path = str(input(r"Enter the input path: "))

import win32com.client as win32
import os

file_links = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        full_file_name_link = os.path.join(input_path, file)
        file_links.append(full_file_name_link)

for link in file_links:
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    book = excel.Workbooks.Open(link)
    is_completed = False


    for i in book.VBProject.VBComponents:
        num_lines = i.CodeModule.CountOfLines 

        for j in range(1, num_lines+1): #iterating num_lines

            if 'Sub' in i.CodeModule.Lines(j, 1) and not 'End Sub' in i.CodeModule.Lines(j, 1):
                module_name = i.CodeModule.Lines(j, 1).split(' ')[1].replace("()", "")
                print(module_name)
                excel.Application.Run(module_name) #Running the MACRO
                book.Save()
                book.Close()
                is_completed = True
                break
        if is_completed:
            break

    excel.Application.Quit()
    del excel
```

[image: The image shows the name of al the button. And I want to fetch all the names.]

Comment: ```break``` ends the loop, so remove that. You also close the book after you find the first sub.

Comment: Hi, @Warcupine thanks for replying. The way what you have said is working fine but I'm getting all the functions name including the button name. But I want only those functions' names which are connected to the button.

Comment: output:
----------------
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Worksheet_Activate
----------------
Ark2
clCalendar
----------------
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Class_Initialize
----------------
----------------
Sub StartCal()
StartCal
----------------



This O/P consists of both. And I want to fetch only functions' names which are related to button name only.